# Magento2: How to delete module installed via composer

Tags: magento2

I want delete one module installed before via composer.

So I first disable module:
List of disabled modules:

```
Scommerce_Core
Scommerce_GoogleRemarketing
```

next:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall Scommerce_Core 
php bin/magento module:uninstall Scommerce_GoogleRemarketing
```

Now I delete folder from `vendor/scommerce` and is issue on website. How to delete it?

update code:

```
arning: require(/home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/../scommerce/core/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Warning: require(/home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/../scommerce/core/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/../scommerce/core/registration.php' (include_path='/home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/local/php71/lib/php') in /home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Comment: What is the issue in website ?

Comment: no path / invalid path to module scommerce / etc located in vendor/ etc

Comment: Have you run setup:upgrade command after disabling modules ?

Comment: Yes, but look like still this module is enabled in website..

Comment: I updated my topic - I get this issue after delete (change name) in vendor/scommerce

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are uninstalling a package installed via composer you also need to run

composer remove vendor/package

So the actions are...

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r {{module_name}}
composer remove vendor/package
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```